# Way too much extra padding on bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have way too much padding at the bottom of my page and I have no idea why it is there. I have looked at Firebug in Firefox, but can't seem to find out which element is causing the extra padding. I know it will be really stupid, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Thanks for helping out!

The site can be found by clicking [here](http://retailsitecommon.afstores.com/Develop/FreshMarket/locations.html).

**EDIT:**
I just realized that this is an issue specific to Firefox. It looks like I would expect when I load the page in Safari. Any idea why Firefox would render the page with an extra 200 or so pixels at the bottom of the page (which causes the browser to have scroll bars when the page doesn't require them).

Thanks for the suggestions already given!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just looked at the site. Remove

```
.cf:before, .cf:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

It's on line 1361. If you turn off either property the extra space goes away. To find it I just methodically deleted each piece of html in firebug until the culprit was found, then started turning off properties one by one.

Nice site.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This was definitely the culprit, but I need that code for other parts of my site. I had just applied it to the bottomLineContainer DIV and it was creating an issue on this page (even though it doesn't on other pages). Removing this class from that DIV did the trick though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Check line 1197 of your stylesheet (`styles.css`).

The height of `div.bottomLineContainer` is being set to `200px`. Try changing the value to `100px` instead.

Answer (score -1):

I would check the extra DIV statement you have listed below the contact us banner. Try removing them and see what happens. I will check on my end in the meantime.
It's your shadowbox which is causing the extra space, i tried loading the page without it and there was no extra padding on the bottom. Check documentation for the shadowbox.